# How can I find only the catalogs and sort them by size

Tags: disk-usage, sort

How can I find only the catalogs and sort them by the size (human-readable).

I tried with

```
find -type d | xargs du -h | sort -rn
```

But something goes wrong.
And all the time its sorted by the numbers. So it doesn't see the difference between K, M etc.

Comment: Do you want it to be recursive, or list per root directory?

Comment: list per root directory.

Comment: Then `--max-depth=1` is a start when it comes to `du`. As in: skip `find` and do `du --max-depth=1 -h . | sort -hr` (If your tools support the options.) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks a lot!  May ask u also why there is a dot ? W

Comment: It is the target directory. Added an answer.

Comment: What is a catalog? Could you please clarify your question? Also you are using the `find` command incorrectly, you need to specify a target directory as Sukminder said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (perhaps) use:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h some_target_directory | sort -hr
```

given the version of the tools has the options available.

To skip the *total*; something like:

```
du --max-depth=1 -h some_target_directory | sort -hr | tail -n +2
```